# WordPress conditional statement how to exclude several page templates and also a taxonomy archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have code in my header that excludes certain templates. I need to change it to also exclude an archive page for my Custom Post type. The file name for the archive template is `taxonomy-press_category.php`.

But I don't know how to also include my custom post type archive template.

I am currently using:

```php
if ( ! is_page_template ( array( 'homepage_template.php', 'services_template.php') ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend reading the "Docs" first. It'll help you get your question answered quicker!

> *"I need to change it to also exclude an archive page for my Custom Post type"*

To exclude an archive page you could use `!is_archive()` and `!is_post_type_archive()`. To include it, then remove the `!`.

> [`is_archive`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/)

and

> [`is_post_type_archive`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/)

```php
if (is_post_type_archive('name-of-your-custom-post-type')){

  // Write your code

}
```

Since you mentioned something about taxonomy, although it was not clear, `is_tax()` could be another conditional check that might be useful.

> [`is_tax`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/)

Again I highly recommend reading the "Docs", or at least, include the details of your problem in a clear way so that people could help you faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your references, that helped.

This is the code that finally worked for me:

```
  if( !is_page_template ('homepage_template.php') &&  !is_page_template( 'services_template.php' )  &&  !is_tax( 'press_category' )) {
```